# ArrayList return size() zero

Tags: java, android, arraylist

mNewList return size() zero but it contains data that it show in ListView, mListData.getContacts(); returns ArrayList fetched from server via internet but its not a problem as i written before it shows data in ListView.

```
ArrayList<String> mNewList = new ArrayList<String>();
mNewList = mListData.getContacts();
Log.i("ShowingListSize", ":" +mNewList.size());

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, 
                                   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                   mNewList);
mList.setAdapter(adapter);

ListData Class

public ArrayList<String> getContacts() {

// Fetch list data from the database
    task = new LoadList();
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    task.execute(new String[]{Integer.toString(day),           
                              Integer.toString(month),   
                              Integer.toString(year),
                              Integer.toString(hour),    
                              Integer.toString(minute)});
    try {
        task.get(); // wait for task to finish
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mContacts;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            try {
                if(response.equals("error")) {
                    return;
                }
                
                json = new JSONObject(response);
                jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("result");
                String number, id;
                
                try{
                    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject arrayItems = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        number = arrayItems.getString("number");
                        id = arrayItems.getString("id");
                        mContacts.add("hello" +number);
                        mContacts.add("hello" +id);
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You sure you're not clearing this `ArrayList` somewhere else? I think you'll need to provide more code for us to help you.

Comment: Where are you doing that? Can you please update your code?

Comment: Is that your actual code? This is unnecessary: `mNewList = new ArrayList<String>();` because in the next line you throw away your newly created object. Use `List<String> mNewList = mListData.getContacts()` instead.

Comment: mListData.getContacts() <--- show the code here

Comment: @simer you need to post you wrote for mListData.getContacts()

Comment: Then check the `ArrayList` you're returning there. Is it empty as well?

Comment: How does that method return the list if you're using an AsyncTask?  Maybe your code in onPostExecute() is what's populating the ListView. Regardless, mNewList must be empty at that point that you log the size.  Post your AsyncTask onPostExecute().

Comment: Looks like you make an adpater.notifyDataSetChanged() in on post execute or something like that. It will explain why the listview is populated

Answer (score 1):

Your getContacts AsyncTask runs in another thread (asynchronously as the etymology suggests). Your list is updated after that thread finishes, but your Logging happens in parallel with the AsyncTask so at the time you log the size, the list *does* contain nothing. Later when the AsyncTask finishes that's when you see things displayed in the list.

Heres a visualization

Thread: **UI** ----------------------------------------------------------- **ASYNCTASK**

............... | .. ArrayList mNewList = new ...;

............... | .. mNewList = mListData.getContacts();

............... | .. AsyncTask::onBeforeExecute()

............... | .............................................................................. | .. AsyncTask::doInBackground starts

............... | .. Log.i(mNewList.size()); .................................... | .. *( still working )*

............... | .............................................................................. | .. AsyncTask::doInBackground returns

............... | .. AsyncTask::onPostExecute

............... | .. mContacts.add(...) ...

............... | ...

Comment: Sorry, i have no idea what you mean by that

Comment: That really defeats the entire purpose of the async task, in any case you're goign to need to post your full example then if you need more help

Comment: Like I said, post the full example then, you're creating one problem but youve posted a question that implies another, either post all of the code or you cant get help. But if youre using get() why bother with an asynctask at all?

Comment: !? If you don't want it to happen in the background WHY use an AsyncTask??

Comment: Think about how ridiculous what you've just said is. Your app will hang if you run network stuff on the UI thread (correct)... so you get a new thread with async task (correct)... but then you use get() to run it on the UI thread anyway... it will STILL hang. Just because the IDE cant spot it and warn you doesnt mean the problem doesnt exist!

Comment: And to preempt your response of 'but I only let get() wait for n seconds... Well if your app would hang because your network takes longer... then cutting off the network after n seconds means the app will *break* instead when the task isnt finished as expected

Comment: That's just to help you learn - the real issue behind your question still needs addressing though so fix the problem so it gets taken off-hold

Comment: Actually simer this answer does serve a purpose for other readers who make a mistake because they also dont understnad the async issue. Theres no need to delete, jsut fix

Comment: sorry nick i don't mean what you get, i mean my question is of no use but i cannot delete it because if there is any answer i cannot delete my question, and whats the way then if i dont use task.get()